# AutoGenerateColumns="False" Causes Empty RadGrid on Databind

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

If `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` then the grid will bind with the dataset and shows the data, but if set to false will not bind and will show the NoRecords value, even though the datatable has rows.

What causes this, and how can I fix it?

```
pas.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns =false;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("SNo");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Add");

DataRow dsa = dt.NewRow();

dsa["SNo"] = "1";
dsa["Name"] = "Karthik";
dsa["Add"] = "Hyd";

dt.Rows.Add(dsa);

dsa = dt.NewRow();
dsa["SNo"] = "2";
dsa["Name"] = "krishna";
dsa["Add"] = "Hyd";
dt.Rows.Add(dsa);

dsa = dt.NewRow();
dsa["SNo"] = "3";
dsa["Name"] = "kailas";
dsa["Add"] = "Hyd";
dt.Rows.Add(dsa);

dsa = dt.NewRow();
dsa["Sno"] = "4";
dsa["Name"] = "Billa";
dsa["Add"] = "Hyd";
dt.Rows.Add(dsa);

dsa = dt.NewRow();
dsa["Sno"] = "5";
dsa["Name"] = "asdf";
dsa["Add"] = "qwer";

dt.Rows.Add(dsa);

pas.DataSource = dt;
pas.DataBind();
```

Comment: Show your RadGrid Markup

Comment: am unable to post my code its showing code format in corract

Comment: <telerik:RadGrid ID="pas" runat="server" Height="100" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
   <ClientSettings>
   <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true"/>
   </ClientSettings> 
   </telerik:RadGrid>

Comment: pas.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns =false; and i kept this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AutoGenerateColumns` property being set to `True` instructs the grid to use whatever columns are returned from the database in your grid, so if you turn this off (`False`), then the grid will have no columns unless you define them, like this:

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductID" 
                             DataType="System.Int32" 
                             HeaderText="Product ID"
                             SortExpression="ProductID" 
                             UniqueName="ProductID">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductName" 
                             HeaderText="Product Name" 
                             SortExpression="ProductName"
                             UniqueName="ProductName">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UnitPrice" 
                             DataType="System.Decimal" 
                             HeaderText="Unit Price"
                             SortExpression="UnitPrice" 
                             UniqueName="UnitPrice">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

You would use `AutoGenerateColumns=False` if you did not want all of the columns from the database query in the grid or if you did not like the names of the columns, because it uses the database field name (i.e. `SYSTEM_ID`).

Comment: Kailas - glad this helped you out, feel free to up-vote this answer when you can. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false and you do not have manually defined columns there will be no columns in RadGrid. Since there are no columns there will be no records because records are cells of given columns. Since there are no rows in the Grid the NoRecordsToDisplay message will be shown. Check this link to view add column manualy.

[click here for deatils](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-programmatic-creation.html)

Comment: Thanks ...but i din,t get solution